# Python Codeacademy: Making a list with a string

Tags: python, list

I'm pondering if I could convert this line of code into a list for all these vowels;

```
if first== 'a' or first =='e' or first == 'i' or first == 'o' or first =='u':"
```

I'm thinking `str[a,e,i,o,u]`

```
pyg = 'ay'
first = original[0]
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print original.lower()
    if first== 'a' or first =='e' or first == 'i' or first == 'o' or first =='u':
        print "vowel"
    else:
        print "consonant"
else:
    print 'empty'


word = original
```

Comment: You should probably move `first = original[0]` *after* `original = raw_input('Enter a word:')`

Answer (score 1):

```
if first.lower() in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
    print "vowel"
else:
    print "consonant"
```

I think the word you are looking for (**Beuller**) is **Boolean**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string instead of a list:

```
if first in "aeiou":
   print "vowel"
else:
   print "consonant"
```

Bear in mind that your current code prints the first letter in lowercase, but doesn't actually change it to lowercase. You could use:

```
if first.lower() in "aeiou":
```

Comment: Because a string is semantically a list of characters, and Python wants to make things easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, str types are like list types in many ways. One of those ways is that the simple and succinct `in` keyword works just fine for testing membership in both.

```
pyg = 'ay'
first = original[0]
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print original.lower()
    if first in 'aeiou':
        print "vowel"
    else:
        print "consonant"
else:
    print 'empty'


word = original
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here:

```
first = original[0]
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
```

You're trying to access `original` before it's defined, this is a simple fix, as it says in the comment (+1 DaoWen), just swap those two lines.

However, then you check to make sure something was entered:

```
if len(original) > 0
```

But by then, if original doesn't pass that statement, it will have thrown an error with `first = original[0]`, so it may be better to hold off assigning `first` until you're in the `if` block:

```
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print original.lower()
    first = original[0].lower()
    if first in ['a','e','i','o','u']: print "vowel"
    else: print "consonant"
else:
    print 'empty'

word = original
```